Distributive Laws between Isomorphic Monads
Let $(S,\eta^S,\mu^S)$, $(T,\eta^T,\mu^T)$ and $(T',\eta^{T'},\mu^{T'})$ be monads on $\mathbf{Set}$. Suppose that the functors $T$ and $T'$ are isomorphic, where natural isomorphisms $\alpha:T\to T'$ and $\beta:T'\to T$ are known. Also, suppose that a distributive law $\lambda':ST'\to T'S$ exists.
My goal is to prove that a distributive law $\lambda:ST\to TS$ exists too. So far this is not guaranteed, but what if I make the stronger assumption that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are (inverse) monad isomorphisms in the 2-category of monads on $\mathbf{Set}$? Does this suffice to state that $\lambda$ exists? If so, why is that true?

This is transport of structures across isomorphisms.

In HoTT a monad isomorphism gives you an identification $(T, \eta^T, \mu^T) = (T', \eta^{T'}, \mu^{T'})$ along which you can directly transport $\lambda'$.

@Trebor No. $\alpha$ isn't assumed to be a morphism of monads.

@NaïmFavier This is only true if $\alpha$ is an isomorphism of monads. And of course using any part of HoTT for this kind of problem is overkill.

@rodirouq Please provide more context. Why do you believe that this statement is true? Are you really demanding just an isomorphism if the functors? And of course we may ignore $\beta$, it is superfluous, it's existence follows by considering $\alpha^{-1}$.

@MartinBrandenburg I did say "monad isomorphism", as that is what the question is about. HoTT is overkill in the same sense that ZFC is overkill; it's just a nicer foundation to think about these issues in.

The title speaks of an isomorphism of monads. The body speaks of an isomorphism of the underlying functors.

Read until the end.

@MartinBrandenburg to avoid any ambiguities, my aim is to prove the statement when $\alpha$ in an isomorphism of monads. if you need more context than that, i will provide it (i'm trying to apply this to a specific example of $S,T$ and $T'$
